# Powershell with excel on Newline characters

Tags: excel, powershell

I have some values in excel which has new line characters in the cell.

Like

```
1.Login to application
2.Do this
3.Do that
```

I did a find and replace in excel and removed the new line by using the method in this link (https://howtoexcelatexcel.com/excel-tips-tricks/find-and-replace-line-breaks-in-excel/)

When i read the values from excel using powershell , it again brings the new line values instead of single line.

Can you please correct my error. I would expect all the values in cell in a single line . removing all the new line .

Code I tried in powershell.

```
$Cellvalue = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,6).Text
```

Comment: Did you save the file after deleting the newlines?

Comment: yes. Is there any other way to remove newline in PowerShell after getting the data ?

Comment: Are you exporting the data from posh to excel?

Comment: yes. Reading the data from excel to powershell

Comment: i also tried $Cellvalue.Replace("'n"," ") and $Cellvalue.Replace("\n"," ") but it s not replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Replace()` string method does not use regex, which you will need to replace newline characters.

This should work:

```
$Cellvalue = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,6).Text -replace '(\r?\n)+', ' '
```

Regex details:

```
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \r        Match a carriage return character
      ?      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \n        Match a line feed character
)+           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```